# I want to write a method to upsert the order to the orders list

Tags: c#

I got this error and I don't know how I should fix it:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.''

This method is supposed to add the new order to the list of orders:

```
public int UpsertOrderItem(OrderItem item)
    {
        int result = 0;
        sqlConn.Open();
        sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_UpsertOrderItem(@description, @price, @quantity)", sqlConn);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", item.Description);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", item.Price);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", item.Quantity);           
        result = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConn.Close();
        return result;         
    }
```

and it is my OrderItem class:

```
public class OrderItem
{
    public OrderItem(OrderHeader order, int stockItemId, decimal price, string description, int quantity)
    {
        
        OrderHeader = order;
        StockItemId = stockItemId;
        Price = price;
        Quantity = quantity;
        Description = description;

    }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public OrderHeader OrderHeader { get; set; }
    public int OrderHeaderId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int StockItemId { get; set; }        
    public decimal Total
    {
        get
        {
            return Price * Quantity;
        }
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Your `OrderItem` has a constructor that accepts more than one parameter, yet you only pass it one.

Comment: @CodeCaster I tried to pass all the arguments, but it doesn't work

Comment: This exception ocurrs when you try to read a property on an object who is not there. In your code, the only place I find this scenario is when your read, for example: item.Description. You could first check whether item is different to null to avoid this error. Depending on your logic is what you should do if item is null.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using SqlCommand? Why are you using the `sp_` prefix? Why are you not using an ORM? Why are you performing a read, not an insert/update, and ignoring the input parameter `item` as well as the resulting `newOrder` object in a method that's called `Upsert` anyway?

Your constructor parameters read: `OrderHeader order, int stockItemId, decimal price, string description, int quantity`. You need to pass all those things, in that order.

You don't have an `OrderHeader`, you have an `OrderHeaderId`. You probably need to add a join to the OrderHeader table in your stored procedure and return that as well, or you need to rethink the entire approach of this method and the code base at large.

Comment: I'm so new in programming and of course it would answer most of your questions. also I'm writing this code like this as they asked to use sp_UpsertOrderItem from Sql server.
If you can tell me more how to write it efficiently I would be grateful